# Remote controller load testing

Tags: load, testing, agent

I am trying to run a load test from remote controller and I get this error.

Failed to queue test run 'username@computername 2010-04-15 06:06:03': Object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting.LoadTestConstantLoadProfile' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestLoadProfile'.

Running unit test from remote controller works just fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Failed to queue test run 'username@MYCONTROLLER 2008-06-13 11:17:28': Object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting.LoadTestConstantLoadProfile' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestLoadProfile'.

or some error related to “Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools…” (ref). Or, you may have a web test that runs fine on one machine but not on another.

If you’ve seen something like this, you’ve probably installed something out of order, or some users have Service Pack 1 installed and some don’t.  A proper install order looks something like:

Visual Studio (Team Edition)
Team Explorer
Team Foundation 2008 October Power Tools
Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1